# SELECT * FROM table WHERE "substring" IN table_field?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
id | url
---------
1  | "facebook.com/user"
2  | "stackoverflow.com/question/"
3  | "facebook.com/videos"
```

So basically I want to extract rows 1 and 2 if I were to try and find urls that have "facebook" in them.

And I'm not sure how to query for that, please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `LIKE` operator

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE url LIKE '%facebook%'
```